# how to create a lib file in rails that executes a script file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a file my_file.rb inside #{Rails.root}/lib/my_file.rb that executes a script my_script residing in #{Rails.root}/script/my_script. I intend to use it like so:

```
script/first_script # this first script will call a method in
# lib/my_file.rb that will run the script/my_script file.
```

How can i create such a lib file that can execute a script? and what is the command to execute a script from a lib file?

Comment: Isn't it easier to use script/runner any_file.rb? Why do you need so complex structure?

Comment: the script does some tasks, and we usually execute it like so: script/any_file > result.log 2> error.log, and then we manually parse the result.log. we need to rewrite the script so that it runs a lib file, which calls the second script using: script/second_script result.log 2> error.log, and then the lib file can access and parse the result.log and present results.

Comment: You might need the `popen3` approach if you want to do that, as it bypasses the need for intermediate log-files. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "execute the script" you mean run it in a separate process, then what you need is the `system` call.

**Update**:

You can also use the [popen3](http://apidock.com/ruby/Open3/popen3) method if you want to capture `STDOUT` and `STDERR` independently. From the example:

```
Open3.popen3("#{Rails.root}/script/my_script") do |in, out, err|
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

here's the list of various options to run a process (in answer to your question, basically you define the method within that lib/xxx.rb, then call that method, and within that method, you run system or what not: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Running_Multiple_Processes